# Cannot import tensorflow_probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I try to `import tensorflow_probability`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow_probability
  File "PATH", line 75, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
  File "PATH", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python import edward2
  File "PATH", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental.edward2.generated_random_variables import *
  File "PATH", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental import auto_batching
  File "PATH", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow_probability.python.experimental.auto_batching import frontend
  File "PATH", line 46, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct import compiler
ImportError: cannot import name 'compiler' from 'tensorflow.python.autograph.pyct' (PATH)
```

I don't know why Python can't import this module because when I type `pip list` in cmd, it tells me that I have `tensorflow-probability 0.8.0rc0` installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Michael_Chen did you find the solution? I've the same Error

Comment: @Nacho no +would you mind starting a bounty on this question? I don't any rep to spare but I still need the answers

Comment: Thanks for reply @Michael Chen, I was using Anaconda. The installation from conda seems to be brocken. Whan I installed from PIP the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to import in `Google colab` and `Ubuntu 18` version. In `colab` it worked directly, in ubuntu I faced issues.
Upgrading to the latest pip and TensorFlow version resolved my issue.

**Colab:**

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
```

**Ubuntu 18:**

Upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

install the latest version of TensorFlow

```
pip install tensorflow
```

install tensorflow_probability

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability
```

tensorflow-probability version `0.11.1`

Comment: it didn't solve for me, on www.saturncloud.io

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the `tf_agents` package.
I had a few import errors appear when trying to import `tensorflow_probability`. These include:

- `module 'tensorflow.python.ops.linalg.linear_operator' has no attribute 'make_composite_tensor'`
- `cannot import name 'all_util' from 'tensorflow_probability.python.internal'`.

These issues were resolved when I installed and imported `tf_agents`.

```
pip install --upgrade tf_agents
```

If you're using jupyter, add the following to a cell and then run it:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade tf_agents
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem. Removing older tensorflow version and **installing everything nightly solved my problem**.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip uninstall tensorflow-probability

pip install tf-nightly
pip install tfp-nightly
```